# How do I access this body data in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm working on Apple MDM, when a device contacts my server and I dump the request, I can see this (among other things):

```
 _contentType: 'application/x-apple-aspen-mdm-checkin',
  body: <Buffer 03 04 05 06 07 ...>,
```

I am using restify and restify bodyParser()

I have obfuscated the actual hex. Now, when I convert the hex to ascii I can see this body string is the very beginning of a PLIST, but not the whole PLIST.

It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>?<!DOCTYPE pl
```

How can I access all of the data, is it in a buffer or something? I am new to nodeJS, so I don't really know how to go about accessing it.

Comment: How are you converting the Buffer to ASCII?

Comment: I'm just taking what was logged, which is <Buffer some hex ...> I take the hex, and put it into a hex to ascii converter and see what is displayed.

Comment: What is displayed is not the sum total of what is there. Try `body.toString()`

Comment: Cool... I added this as the answer... please accept when you get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at data on the console, what you're seeing is some interpretation that your debugger has chosen to use. For large items, this is often a truncated representation.

```
body.toString()
```

will do a full conversion for you.